# How do I disable KeyboardListener when the focus is in TextField?

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement of using arrow keys to move between `PageView` pages, which I achieved with `KeyboardListener`. However some pages may include a `TextInput` and if that `TextInput` is focused, I want to prevent the `KeyboardListener` to handle the arrow keys.

The only solution I can think of is to set some flag when `TextInput` gains focus and condition the arrow logic, but this does not look elegant at all (since the `KeyboardListener` is way up the Widget tree and I would need to wire that logic to every `TextInput`).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

1. Extended `FocusNode` to have class indicating that for given Widget global keyboard events should be ignored:

```dart
class IgnoreShortcutKeysFocusNode extends FocusNode {}
```

2. In Widgets that contain a `TextInput`, I first create the extended `IgnoreShortcutKeysFocusNode` and assign it to the `TextInput`:

```dart
final _focusNode = IgnoreShortcutKeysFocusNode();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextField(
    focusNode: _focusNode,
    // ...
  );
}
```

3. In `KeyboardListener` handler, I check what is the currently focused node and act accordingly:

```dart
void _handleKeyEvent(KeyEvent value) {
  if (FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus is IgnoreShortcutKeysFocusNode) return;
  // arrow key handling
}
```

This is not ideal since the `IgnoreShortcutKeysFocusNode` must be added to each `TextInput`, but it works.